# What does recv() write into bufferif data received is less than buffer's length

Tags: c, sockets, recv

I'm trying to write a server in C using sockets which will be receiving commands from multiple clients. What I'm trying to understand is: if the client sends command which consists of, say, 4 characters, while recv() function is told to receive 5 bytes of data, what will happen?

Here's my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void *connection_handler(void *);
int sendall(int s, char *buf, int len, int flags);
int recvall(int s, char *buf, int len, int flags);

int main (int argc , char *argv[])
{
char check = 'n', *message;
int socket_d, port, socket_n, *sock_n, c;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;

socket_d = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_d == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket. Exiting...\n");
    return 1;
}

printf("Welcome to Random server v0.0.1.\n");

printf("Please input port (default - 3425): ");
scanf("%i", &port);
if (port >= 65536 || port < 0) port = 3425;
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

if( bind(socket_d,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr , sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
{
    printf("Binding socket failed.\n");
    return 1;
}
printf("Binding socket done.\n");

listen(socket_d, 3);

printf("Waiting for connections...\n");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

while( (socket_n = accept(socket_d, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");
        message = "Hello Client, I have received your connection. And now I will assign a handler for you\n";
        send(socket_n , message , strlen(message), 0);

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        sock_n = malloc(1);
        *sock_n = socket_n;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) sock_n) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

if (socket_n<0)
    {
        printf("Accept failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
return 0;
}
void *connection_handler(void *socket_d)
{
printf("Thread created\n");
int sock = *(int*)socket_d;
int read_size;
char *message , client_message[200];

while (1)
{
    message = malloc(5);
    read_size = recv(sock , message , 5 , 0);
    strcpy(client_message, message);
    //send(sock , message , strlen(message), 0);
    free(message);

    if (strcmp(client_message, "list") == 0)
    {
        DIR * dir;
        struct dirent * de;
        strcpy(client_message, "");
        if ((dir = opendir(".")) == NULL ) strcpy(client_message, "Unable to open the directory.\n");
        else
        {
            while (de = readdir(dir)) {strcat(client_message, de->d_name); strcat(client_message, "\n"); }
        }
        closedir(dir);
        send(sock, client_message, strlen(client_message), 0);
        continue;
    }
    if (strcmp(client_message, "date") == 0)
    {
        time_t rtime;
        rtime = time (NULL);
        strcpy(client_message, ctime(&rtime));
        send(sock, client_message, strlen(client_message), 0);
        continue;
    }
    if (strcmp(client_message, "mkdir") == 0)
    {
        int result_code = mkdir("./new dir");
        if (result_code == 0) strcpy(client_message, "OK");
        else strcpy(client_message, "ERROR");
        send(sock, client_message, strlen(client_message), 0);
        continue;
    }
    if (strcmp(client_message, "exit") == 0)
    {
        strcpy(client_message, "Bye");
        send(sock, client_message, strlen(client_message), 0);
        break;
    }
    send(sock, client_message, strlen(client_message), 0);


    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        printf("Client disconnected\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        break;
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        printf("Recv failed\n");
    }
}

printf("Thread will now be deleted.\n");
free(socket_d);

return 0;
}
```

As of now, it seems that it will write those 4 characters into buffer AND something else, to make it five bytes long. Am I correct? What exactly is happening? How could I make it so that server could process commands of any length?

Comment: The fifth byte is unchanged - it still has the value it had before the call to recv()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As of now, it seems that it will write those 4 characters into buffer AND something else, to make it five bytes long. Am I correct?

No. [`recv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) will read up to a maximum of the number of bytes requested, but *may* read less. From linked reference page:

> ...The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested.

The *something else* being witnessed is because the buffer `recv()` is populating is unitialized:

```
message = malloc(5); /* Uninitialized. */
read_size = recv(sock , message , 5 , 0);
```

Meaing if only 4 bytes are read the fifth byte in the buffer will contain a random value.

The posted code incorrectly uses `strcpy()`, which is dependent upon the presence of a null terminating character: use the return value of `recv()` to know exactly how many bytes were read and also if it fails completely (in which the case the return value is `-1`). For example:

```
read_size = recv(sock , message , 5 , 0);
if (read_size != -1)
{
    if (read_size == 4 && memcmp(message, "list", 4) == 0)
    {
    }
}
else
{
    /* Report failure. */
}
```

> How could I make it so that server could process commands of any length?

To do this a mechanism is required to indicate the end of message. This could be a designated character that cannot appear inside a message or by prefixing the message with the length of the following message.

Comment: If I understood correctly, using strncpy(client_message, message, read_size) instead of strcpy() should do the trick, right?

Comment: What if there is not enough room for the null character? From [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy): _If count is reached before the entire string src was copied, the resulting character array is not null-terminated._

Comment: @user3201961: remember, `strncpy()` does not guarantee a null-terminated output string.  It is crucial to remember that, because the commonest mistake in using `strncpy()` is to forget to ensure that the string is null terminated.  The other problem with `strncpy()` is that if you have a 64 KiB buffer as the target, `strncpy()` will write 64 KiB each time it copies, even if the source string is 3 bytes plus a null byte long.  If you didn't know that, go read the specification of `strncpy()` carefully.

Answer (score 3):

> If the client sends command which consists of, say, 4 characters, while `recv()` function is told to receive 5 bytes of data, what will happen?

The buffer will contain 4 bytes of data and the length information returned by `recv()` will tell you that there are 4 bytes of valid data and therefore there is nothing reliable in the fifth byte (but it is most probably what was there before the `recv()` call was made). Since your code does not send the null at the end of the null-terminated string, the receiving code does not get a null, so you cannot use `strcpy()` reliably on the received data.  Use `memmove()` or `memcpy()` or perhaps `strncpy()` and then null terminate.

If you want to send arbitrarily long messages, you have two main options.  One is to specify an upper bound on the length of a single message, allocate enough space to receive that, and carefully note how much was received. The other is to use a variant on [TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) (type, length, value) format so the sender indicates the type and length of the data plus the actual data, and the receiver can read the type and length, allocate enough space, and then read the value.